# Black Screen Error instead elementary OS logo when Madcatz Strike5 Keyboard is pluged

Tags: boot

I am already tried looking for my problem in this forum without no lucky, it seems to me just an aesthetics thing but it is a little annoying. I have a gamer keyboard (MadCatz Strike 5), and when it's plugged and I turn the computer on, the system, instead of shows the elementary OS logo, it shows a black screen with 3 "errors" and I couldn't find anything about them. i attached a picture where you will be able too see the screenshot. Do you have any suggestions?

It's important to point, that this black screen only appears when the keyboard is plugged.

[image]

Comment: Try kernel 4.4.

Comment: I installed kernel 4.5 following your suggestion and now i can see the Elementary Logo!!!! , i had to uninstall propietary nvidia drivers and install xorg noveau drivers before to make the kernel update, the problem is, now i can't install propietary drivers (i mean i can do it from additional drivers), because Graphical environment doens't work, and with noveau i feel the "animations" slower than before. Any suggestion?

Comment: For me it wasn't slow.I have AMD but you have NVIDIA.I also couldn't install the AMD drivers

Comment: I will post as an answer since the NVIDIA driver is something else which you could ask as another question

Comment: Is your system heating up

Comment: i tried with kernel 4.5 and 4.4 and changing nvidia's version drivers until i got only 600*400 resolution, so i uninstalled all graphics driver (nvidia and nouveau) put the 4.0 kernel, and then download nvidia driver from nvidia official website, i got full resolution (2560*1080) so i think it  works , except a little detail, the elementary logo seems "pixeled" and big. Any last suggestion to correct this little detail?

Comment: Try changing GRUBs resolution. If you use rEFInd try changing its resolution

Comment: finally i edited grub's configuration files and i could put 1920*1080, now TTY's, elementary Logo and Grub resolution are perfect. Thank a lot your suggestions were so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, pointing that i have Nvidia 960

Step 1
Download and install Kernel 4.0 Packages from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/

In my case for x64

```
linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.0.0-040000_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_all.deb
linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic_4.0.0-040000.201504121935_amd64.deb
```

and install the new kernel

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.*.deb linux-image-4.*.deb
```

And Nvidia last drivers from it official website (you will download as a script i think, so you will have to give it execute permissions with chmod +x)

http://www.nvidia.es/Download/index.aspx?lang=es

Step 2 Uninstall nvidia's and nouveau's drivers

For get no errors, i did it in recovery mode, in a console as root, you will need reading and writing permissions

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

For some reason when i did that the first time, comand return me an "error", the second time i wrote the sentence, it worked.

once i got reading/writting permissions i proceeded to uninstall all drivers

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau*
```

and install the executable file that you downloaded from nvidia offical website, i will put my file name.

```
cd /home/oliver/Download
 ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.42.run
```

This way now i can access to TTY console, see the elementary logo and Graphical environtment in full resolution.

But ... the elementary logo looks pixelated, TTY in 600x400 so ...

Step 3

In my case for some reason i couldn't install rEFInd as user Suici Doga recommend. So i did manually editing /etc/defaul/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and adding

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080  # not "auto"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

then updating grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

I read that is important to know what resolutions your monitor and grub support before to editing the grub file, you can do it with hwinfo ... i couldn't install it, i think it was because i spent many hours trying to find de complete solution (you know trial and error).

Thanks to user Suici Doga for his help!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Linux kernel 4.5.

To do it run the following in the terminal to download the kernel

For 32-bit

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb
```

For 64-bit

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
```

And then install the kernel (for both 64 and 32)

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.5*.deb linux-image-4.5*.deb
```

Reboot